# Derivative form

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Is there any way to show result like this?

$\text{in[ ]:}\quad x^2 + y^2 = t^2 \\ \text{out[ ]:}\quad 2xdx + 2ydy = 2tdt$

The reason of this asking is I want to show process of many form of derivative. anyway or using $\dot{x}$ or $x'$ may be good as well.

Comment: `Dt[x^2 + y^2 == t^2]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it Solve[d]~ :)